# xubuntu desktop 16.04 display problem

Tags: xubuntu, hardware

I have no problem in login to the system, but the windows of all applications are tiled up to half the screen. I am unable to type in terminal also. The rest of the screen is not accessible. Also the icons
in the desktop are also not visible. The top bar over all applications
are gone which contains application name, maximise, minimise and close 
button.

Your help is much appreciated.

[image: Screen-shot-of-desktop]

```
System:    Host: threeseven Kernel: 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: N/A Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: ASUS product: All Series
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: H81M-CS v: Rev X.0x
           Bios: American Megatrends v: 0402 date: 06/17/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Pentium G3240 (-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2493 MHz 2: 2958 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Desktop
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-50-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: 9c:5c:8e:96:d4:04
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 250.1GB (33.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST3250312AS size: 250.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 138G used: 69G (53%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 10.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 207 Uptime: 10 min Memory: 1136.7/3816.8MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: It seems you're using the wrong resolution.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia shortcut keys are also not working

Comment: So? Likely you don't have the correct graphics drivers installed for your system. Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications. Ping me in comments with @GabrielaGarcia when done so I can try to help you out.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have added the system hardware specifications.

Comment: The part `unloaded: fbdev,vesa` confirms there's no driver for Intel Graphics installed or at least not in use (but it should be). Try `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reboot. If there are error messages make sure to update the question. And if it works I'll post this as an answer later.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-20
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please update your question with the full result of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Updated.